# Extract part of string between two different patterns

Tags: regex, r, text-extraction, stringr

I try to use `stringr` package to extract part of a string, which is between two particular patterns.

For example, I have:

```
my.string <- "nanaqwertybaba"
left.border  <- "nana"
right.border <- "baba"
```

and by the use of `str_extract(string, pattern)` function (where pattern is *defined by a POSIX regular expression*) I would like to receive:

```
"qwerty"
```

Solutions from Google did not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not know whether and how this is possible with functions provided by *stringr* but you can also use base `regexpr` and `substring`:

```
pattern <- paste0("(?<=", left.border, ")[a-z]+(?=", right.border, ")")
# "(?<=nana)[a-z]+(?=baba)"

rx <- regexpr(pattern, text=my.string, perl=TRUE)
# [1] 5
# attr(,"match.length")
# [1] 6

substring(my.string, rx, rx+attr(rx, "match.length")-1)
# [1] "qwerty"
```

Comment: Thank you, sigbb! I have just adjusted it a little bit, so as to: 1. match all characters between `left.border` and `right.border`, 2. match up to first occurence of `right.border` and now I have: `rx <- regexpr(paste0("(?<=", left.border, ")(.*?)+(?=", right.border, ")"), text = my.string, perl = TRUE)`. Big thank you to you!

Answer (score 14):

In `base` R you can use `gsub`. The parentheses in the `pattern` create numbered capturing groups. Here we select the second group in the `replacement`, i.e. the group between the borders. The `.` matches any character. The `*` means that there is zero or more of the preceeding element

```
gsub(pattern = "(.*nana)(.*)(baba.*)",
     replacement = "\\2",
     x = "xxxnanaRisnicebabayyy")
# "Risnice"
```

Comment: Well, the point is I do not know that "qwerty" does sit here, do there is no way I use it in the regex pattern!

Comment: @Marciszka: you can replace "qwerty" in this example by an regular expression as well, e.g. `gsub(pattern = "(.*nana)([[:alpha:]]+)(baba.*)", "\\2", x=my.string)` for at least one letter.

Answer (score 7):

I would use `str_match` from **stringr**: "str_match extracts capture groups formed by
() from the first match. It returns a character matrix with one column for the complete match and one column for each group." [ref](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Wickham.pdf)

```
str_match(my.string, paste(left.border, '(.+)', right.border, sep=''))[,2]
```

The code above creates a regular expression with `paste` concatenating the capture group `(.+)` that captures 1 or more characters, with left and right borders (no spaces between strings).

A single match is assumed. So, `[,2]` selects the second column from the matrix returned by `str_match`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package *unglue*:

```
library(unglue)
my.string <- "nanaqwertybaba"
unglue_vec(my.string, "nana{res}baba")
#> [1] "qwerty"
```